# Powershell and PDFTK merge

Tags: powershell, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have a requirement to merge several thousand pdf's each week which have consistent names eg:

- Customer_Invoice_940590.pdf
- Customer_Invoice_940590-details.pdf

In the past I wrote a script that performed this perfectly but alas the script file didn't get backed after a recent OS upgrade. So after rewriting the script (it's been over 2 years) I have it working apart from the merging of the PDFs which Powershell keeps throwing an error unable to find file : *pdftk*

Essentially what I have written pulls the first two PDFs from a folder and moves them to another folder, declare each file as variables, merge the PDFs into a separate output folder, delete variable files. Rinse repeat until all files are merged.

Any thoughts?

Appreciate any help with this and also if there would be a cleaner way to perform this task (I'm sure there is :p)

```
$pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"
$inputFolder = "C:\Dump Here"
$outputFolder = "C:\Combines Files"
$MiddleOutput = "C:\Middle"

$maxItems = 2
$CountyCount = Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}

If ($CountyCount -gt $maxItems) {

    Get-Childitem $inputFolder -filter *.pdf -Recurse |Select-Object -First 2 | Move-Item -Destination $MiddleOutput

    $firstPDF = Get-ChildItem $MiddleOutput -Filter *.pdf | Select-Object -first 1
    $lastPDF = Get-ChildItem $MiddleOutput -Filter *.pdf | Select-Object -last 1

    pdftk $lastPDF $firstPDF cat Output "$outputFolder\November_$lastPDF"

    Remove-Item $firstPDF
    Remove-Item $lastPDF
}
else {
    exit
}
```

Comment: Well, is PDFtk installed and the folder containing `pdftk.exe` in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes, it's installed in the exact directory at the top of the script.

Comment: `pdftk $lastPDF ...` -> `& $pdftk $lastPDF ...`

Comment: So it turns out "$outputFolder\November_$lastPDF" was causing the issue, once the quotes were removed it worked fine.